# Variable inside if statement in javaScript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables

I wonder why my first code doesn't work and the second does. I thought they're basically the same....
Looks like var inside if statement doesn't seem to be processed as expected. Could anyone please clarify why it doesn't work?

```js
var myFarm = ["chickens", "pigs", "cows", "horses", "ostriches"];
var letterCheck = myFarm[i].charAt(0);

for (var i = 0; i < myFarm.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}

if (letterCheck === "c" || letterCheck === "o") {
    alert("Starts with 'c' or 'o'!");
}
```

---

```js
var myFarm = ["chickens", "pigs", "cows", "horses", "ostriches"];
var arrayLength = myFarm.length;


for (var j = 0; j < arrayLength; j++) {

    console.log(myFarm[j]);


    if (myFarm[j].charAt(0) === "c" || myFarm[j].charAt(0) === "o") {

        alert("Starts with a c or an o!");
    }

}
```

Comment: In the first example, you refer to `i` _before_ the loop that uses `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good reason to avoid `var` in favor of `let` or `const` when writing modern JavaScript: confusion around *hoisting*.  With `var` declarations, the *declaration* is hoisted to the top of the scope but the *assignment* doesn't get hoisted; it occurs at the line at which it is assigned in the code as written.  So we can see if we add a console log:

```js
var myFarm = ["chickens", "pigs", "cows", "horses", "ostriches"];

console.log(i)

var letterCheck = myFarm[i].charAt(0);

for (var i = 0; i < myFarm.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}

if (letterCheck === "c" || letterCheck === "o") {
    alert("Starts with 'c' or 'o'!");
}
```

... that `i` is `undefined` at the time you try to use it to get an index off an array.

Answer (score 0):

The first code is trying to get the position [i] from the array, but the variable i does not exist there, it is created in the for loop that is below.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with the first code -
Value of i initialised and incremented in the "for loop" corresponding to myFarm array. so i refers to the actual indexes of the array inside the "for loop", that's where letterCheck and alert condition has to go. Not outside of the "for loop" where i is undefined.